# Can I put a second version of my app on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Because of how my app has evolved I want to split it into two different play stores so I can better describe it.

I can't find info on if this is allowed by Google or not. It would be more or less mostly the same application, but with a different title and description.

Secondly since there are a lot of paid versions of applications, is it fine for me to do this if I make one of the versions a paid version?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Google store policies, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do so, but it requires your app to use a different package name (i.e. a different application id). It will basically be a different app.

Comment: okay thanks. Is it only if it's paid or can I do it if it's free?

Comment: It's a complete different app, so you can do whatever you want, paid or free.